# Excel 2013 + sql query

Tags: sql, excel

Всем привет!

Нужно обновлять из документа Excel данные (самого документа) из Sql Server. Но при этом делать через sql query (в нем сложная выборка). При этом в самом документе нужно иметь возможность задавать параметры фильтрации(даты и тп), то есть нужно связать сам документ Excel с sql query.
Я так понимаю что "напрямую" так сделать не выйдет.

Делал ли кто то подобное или знаете другие варианты ?

Comment: а нельзя получить все данные, а потом уже результат отфильтровать средствами Excel? слишком большой объем? VBA в таком случае скорее всего вам пригодится

Comment: Можно, через Microsoft Query, но оно не совсем нам подходит. Да, насчет макроса я уже думал, без него походу никак. Есть такой вариант(рабочий, из другой команды) - дергаем из Excel exe-файл -> он нам генерит csv файл(по нашему sql query) -> затем дергаем сам Excel что бы он обновился из csv. Но этот вариант мне кажеться несколько "длинным". Вернее сам Excel дергает наверно макрос после того, как завершиться exe

Comment: в справке по крайней мере написано, что можно делать запросы с параметрами, которые вводятся при выполненнии в диалоге. В любом случае вам, наверное, понадобятся макросы, которые будут обновлять датасет при смене значений параметров на листе

Comment: [вот кстати](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/63d15491-21d7-4ad6-bd2a-cdf5b4c03697/ms-query-pass-user-entered-parameter-from-excel-to-access-query?forum=exceldev) нечто похожее на решение

Comment: Примерно так будет(наверно) - з Excel нажимаем Refresh All -> Excel  дергает CMD  -> CMD запускает SQL select -> Select выгружает данные в CSV -> Excel выгребает данные из CSV и сторит отчет

Comment: ссылка. приведенная выше, не является решением? там вроде выполняется параметризованный запрос а параметры из ячеек берутся.

Comment: пока не понятно, подойдет или нет. У нас сложные условия фильтрации, и можно ли тут такое запилить я пока не могу сказать. спасибо за пример)